# Why use typeof() instead of the object type when avoiding block retain cycles?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen this code snippet frequently when other ObjC developer are breaking a retain cycle.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject doThingWithCompletion:^{
    typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf awesomeThingOne];
    [strongSelf moreAwesome];
}];
```

**Why the use of the `typeof()` macro? Is this unique to blocks?**

My initial thought is that `self`'s type might not be known (that seems mostly impossible, but let's pretend...). If the type is unknown, then why not declare `weakSelf` with an `id`: `__weak id weakSelf = self;`?

My second thought is that it's defensive against subclassing, but that seems unlikely to cause an issue. Assume `ObjTwo` subclasses `AwesomeObj` and overrides the `awesomeThingOne` method. The fake code above should work just fine if `self` is an instance of `ObjTwo` or `AwesomeObj`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `typeof()` macro allows a few things.

First of all, personally, I've created a code snippet with this sort of thing.  Instead of having to type out:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
```

each and every time I want to set this up, substituting `MyClass` for the appropriate class, I can instead just start to type `weakSelf` and Xcode's autocomplete will try to offer my this line of code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

That's going to work every time.

---

Also, using `typeof()` gives us an explicit type and minimizes the code to rewrite if we ever change the actual type.

`id` is unsafe and it won't give us auto-completes on available methods and properties.  After all, `weakSelf` is now of type `id` rather than of type `MyClass`.

And we can run into the same problem with subclasses where if I just default to `MyClass`, doing:

```
weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
```

won't give me autocompletes on methods/properties that `MySubClass` added if `self` is actually `MySubClass`.

---

And use of `typeof()` isn't at all limited to blocks.  I like to use `typeof()` in class methods.

Generally, the following is sufficient:

```
+ (instancetype)myInstance {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

As `instancetype` and `[self alloc]` take care of getting the right subclass.

But suppose we want something more complex:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)arrayOfInstances;
```

How can we make sure the objects we stick into the array are of the right type?

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)arrayOfInstances {
    NSMutableArray *instances = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        typeof([self alloc]) newObj = [[self alloc] init];
        newObj.someIntProperty = i;
        [instances addObject:newObj];
    }

    return instances;
}
```

We wouldn't want to use `id` as the type for `newObj`.  We want to be certain that if we call:

```
[MyClass arrayOfInstances];
```

We get an array of `MyClass` objects, but if we call:

```
[MySubClass arrayOfInstances];
```

We get an array of `MySubClass` objects, etc.

---

We could also use `typeof()` if we wanted to instantiate an object from a dictionary that defined our object:

```
Class dynamicType = myDict[@"Class"];
typeof([dynamicType alloc]) myObject = [[dynamicType alloc] init];
myObject.foo = myDict[@"Foo"];
myObject.bar = myDict[@"Bar"];
```

Comment: Why `typeof([self alloc])` and not `typeof(self)`?