# self concept ,if i use self in class method not in instance method

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios5

```
@interface hello:SKScene
@end

@implementation hello

+(void)method{

    [self here];

}
@end
```

main.m

```
[hello method];
```

here,when i call this class method without allocating memory for object then method self,belong to whom????
my question is self belong to class that contain the method calling on then because i did not define object then ,why i still can use self on this?????

is it still belong to class on which it calling ??please give me proper concept of self on instance method and class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to `self` in class method, `self` refers to the class, itself, not to a particular instance of that class. By using `self` rather than the actual class name in these class methods, it makes it easier to subclass the class in question. Specifically, the class method will be inherited, but the `self` references will now refer to the subclass rather than the base class. If you refered to the base class by name, this would not be true.

Consider this factory method:

```
@implementation BaseClassObject

// THIS IS WRONG 

+ (BaseClassObject *)object {
    return [[BaseClassObject alloc] init];
}

@end
```

And consider this subclass:

```
@interface SubClassObject : BaseClassObject
@end
```

Then consider code that does:

```
SubClassObject *object = [SubClassObject object];  // WRONG
```

The problem is that the `object` factory method will return a `BaseClassObject` rather than a `SubClassObject`. But that is remedied if we alter the definition of that factory class method to use `self`:

```
@implementation BaseClassObject

// THIS IS RIGHT 

+ (instancetype)object {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Now when I refer to `[SubClassObject object]`, I'll get an instance of `SubClassObject` rather than `BaseClassObject`.

---

Note: In my contrived example, it's rather important to use `self`. You may, though, encounter code where it does not appear to be immediately relevant (for example, you might have a base class, but no subclass at this time).

Even in this case, you probably should be in the habit of using `self` in these class methods, regardless, to "future-proof" your code, so that if you ever subclass this base class at some unforeseen date in the future, these class methods are more likely to function properly even when subclassed.

Comment: I can't agree fully with "this is right" in the last example http://stackoverflow.com/a/26821507/2792531

Comment: I think best practice would suggest the actual additional configuration goes in an init method, and the factory method just returns the result of that.

Comment: The discussion about what goes in the factory method and what goes into `init` is not really relevant here, but I've removed those comments for you.

Comment: While that may be true, we should strive to post answers that follow best practices. Especially when proclaiming "THIS IS RIGHT" in all caps right next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little to Rob's answer: the class object is created automatically by the compiler and/or Objective-C runtime. (It doesn't matter to you which it is.) For all intents and purposes, it's permanent. There's no need for it to be managed.